# How do I programmatically send MIME HTML emails without using the Rules module?

Tags: emails

In the past, I have used the Rules module to send MIME HTML emails, creating a component and invoking it in my code with `rules_invoke_component('rules_send_html_email', $parameters)`.

How can I programmatically do this without using the Rules module?

I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: Did you look at the code ran from `rules_invoke_component('rules_send_html_email', $parameters)`? If you did, is there anything that you don't exactly understand? Is there anything that you don't understand in converting the code?

Comment: Truthfully, I am just not sure where to start. I looked through the MimeMail module but was confused. Is there a function from the module that I can call in my code that sends an HTML Email? I am new to this. @kiamlaluno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation, it looked like the [drupal_mail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7.x) function worked as long as the [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) and [Mail System](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem) modules were configured.

So you will simply execute the [drupal_mail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7.x) function and also use [hook_mail](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7.x) in your custom module (send_html_email is the module name in this example).

You can use the following code in a re-usable function, after a form is submitted, or anywhere else that you would like an email to be sent:

```
  // Parameters passed to Drupal Mail Function
  $params = array(
    'subject' => $subject,
    'body' => $body,
  );

  // Send the Email!
  drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, language_default(), $params, $from);
```

Now you will need to use [hook_mail](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7.x):

```
// hook_mail()
function send_html_email_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
  $message['body'] = $params['body'];
}
```

Doing this will successfully send an HTML Mime Mail email from your code.

Comment: Your hook_mail() will throw an error, need to pass body as an array: $message['body'] = array('0' => $params['body'];